# asterisk rectangle using while loop

Tags: c++

I have to make an i by j rectangle using while loops....
so far this is as far I got.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void stars(int, int);

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    cin >> i >> j;
    stars(i, j);


    return 0;
}
void stars(int i, int j)
{
    while (j >= 0)
    {

        while (i >= 1)
        {

            cout << "*";
            i = i - 1;

        }
        j = j - 1;

    }
}
```

it shoots out one row of 'i' asterisks.
I (j-1) more rows....

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: I recommend using better variable names than `i` and `j`, for example, `height` and `width` or `row` and `column`.

Comment: you're right drew dormann.
i meant to say i need j-1 more rows

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things wrong with your `stars` code:

1. You need to somehow go to the new line after your row of asterisks is complete
2. If you decrement `i` and never restore it to its original value after the 1st row no more asterisks will be printed

You could try something like this:

```
void stars(int i, int j)
{
    while (j-- > 0)
    {
        int k = i;
        while (k-- > 0)
            cout << "*";

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so how are you decrementing the k value so that you go the next row?